# WAN port redirecting to default router gateway

Tags: router, lan, nat, wan

I have a website on which I'm hosting Citrix NetScaler that is supposed to facilitate external access in my environment.

I have created an A record in my external DNS zone with the router's public IP address and linked it to the website name. Then, I went ahead and created a NAT rule in my router.

The rule is configured to listen on WAN 443 requests and link them to the internal server's IP address. Both the WAN and LAN rules are configured to listen on port 443 since I'm accessing the website via HTTPS.

Now, every time I'm trying to access `https://netscaler.domain.com` I get redirected to my router's default IP address, the link looks something like this: `https://192.168.0.1/html/index.html?url=netscaler.domain.com`

As a troubleshooting step, I have configured the WAN port to something else other than 443 (3443 in this case) and the NAT rule works as expected.

This is a lab environment, and has worked before. I'm guessing port 443 no longer works because something else is using it? If so, can someone recommend some graphical tools that I can use to check what's using this port or otherwise if this is not the case - advise what can be wrong?

PS: I'm using a Windows Server 2012 R2 environment.

The Router is a Huawei B310s-22

Comment: Why a graphical tool? Likely the NetScaler is offering its own configuration interface on that port+ip combination. Did you check your configuration whenever you have the option to setup something like a "host IP" or similar. So you'd use the NAT rule to forward traffic to that IP (which doesn't hose the web interface) and redirects your traffic?

Comment: I was unable to find any errors in NetScaler at all. And yes, I'm redirecting the traffic to a virtual server in netscaler that's hosting the website. I've checked this from a configuration perspective and everything is fine.

I'm not very good at networking, so I need to find a way to see if port 443 is in use by something else other than netscaler. Not sure if this is even the case but I assume so if other ports seem to work just fine

Comment: As a workaround I'm using https://netscaler.domain.com:3443 to access the website, but it should really be https://netscaler.domain.com:443